# Encontrar a pasta do banco Sqlite no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Como encontrar a pasta do banco de dados no android studio ?
Ja tentei tools -> Android -> Android device Monitor, a pasta data está vazia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No codigo de sua aplicação deve ter o endereço de seu db
tente neste endereço...
me avise se deu certo...ok

```
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/br.com.yourapp/databases/";
```

Comment: deu certo. Obg.

Comment: ;) beleza!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Faça os seguintes passos:

1. No Android Studio, vá em **Tools > Android > Device Monitor**
2. No Device Monitor, no canto esquerdo, selecione o dispositivo que está em execução
3. Selecione a aba **File Explorer** do Device Monitor. Nesse momento irão aparecer as pastas que estão no dispositivo em execução
4. Selecione **data > data > pacote.da.sua.aplicação > databases**

Se você quiser baixar e visualizar o arquivo de banco de dados, basta selecionar o arquivo e clicar na opção **Pull a file from device**, que é um icone de um disquete com uma seta rosa que fica no canto superior direito, entre as abas e o explorador de arquivo

Comment: A pasta esta vazia, gostaria de visualizar o banco.

Comment: Se você fez esses passos e o arquivo não está aparecendo, provavelmente você não está criando o banco de maneira correta. O banco é criado dentro da aplicação no método `onCreate()` do `SQLiteOpenHelper` ou vc insere ele como um arquivo na pasta **assets**?

Comment: criando banco dessa forma: @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " + NOME_TABELA
                + " ("
                + ID_USUARIO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NOME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + SENHA + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
        );

    }

Comment: Ok, mas você também tem que garantir que em alguma classe você esteja criando uma instancia do `SQLiteOpenHelper`, porque se vc n fizer isso, o `onCreate()` nunca será chamado e portanto, seu banco não será criado.

Comment: estou garantindo isso, não dar erro algum de banco. A pasta do meu projeto não encontro no meu smartphone.